# How to factor $ ab(x^2 +y^2) + xy (a^2 +b^2)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, soft-question

Source : poblem 291 ( image below)  of Lebossé & Hémery, *Algèbre et Analyse*  ( Classe de seconde , 1965)

Note : " classe de seconde " is $10^{\mathbb th}$ grade , which inspires me the reflection that I wouldn't have be admitted to  $11^{\mathbb th}$ grade in $1965$.

Developping I get ,

$abx^2+ ab y^2 + xy a^2 + xyb^2$

but I cannot see which known identity is hidden below this expression.

Symbolab is unable to give any answer regarding this factorization problem.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just notice that $abx^2 + aby^2 + xya^2 + xyb^2 = ax(bx + ay) + by(bx + ay) = (bx + ay)(ax+by)$

Comment: Thanks ! I failed to notice that !

Comment: @VinceVickler Without noticing that, you could still do it the hard way by considering the expression a quadratic in $x$, finding the roots using the usual quadratic formula, then factoring it.